# Regex Find Title Case With Lower-Case Articles Etc

Tags: java, regex, title-case

I'm looking to match my regex against a HTML string which may include a title at the front. The pattern for the string will be something like this:

```
This Is the Title Using Title Case <br/> This is the rest of the sentences using regular sentence case.
```

I want to catch the title at the start, but I'm having trouble factoring in the lower-case articles and conjugates that are included in this. I managed to find some helpful code for pure title case which works:

```
([A-Z][\w-]*(?:\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)+ <br/>)
```

But I don't know how to structure it to include lower case version of:

```
(a|an|the|and|but|or|on|in|with)
```

Comment: @ctwheels The link to that post causes confusion, not only because of your decorations, but also because this question is not _really_ about parsing (X)HTML.

Comment: @MrLister The *decorations* are extracted from the answer to the question I linked to. Also, it still is matching HTML with regex, regardless of how this question is approached. This being said, yes, it's a very minimalistic example of HTML, which is why I still provided a regex solution. There is likely a better way for the OP to go about solving their problem than using regex in the way they are intending to use it, and it's also likely (based on the actual question itself) that the OP isn't aware of issues related to parsing (X)HTML with regex, so I felt it may be a good read if not more.

Comment: Haha thanks ctwheels! That works pretty well, although I noticed if a word includes an ' it doesn't work. I tried just adding an ' into to the [\w'-] but it didn't seem to do anything.
To be fair, the code only contains <br/> tags (which I replace with /n after identifying the title). I just need to be able to find these titles and remove them, and I felt regex was the simplest way of doing this replaceAll (in Java). What would you recommend for parsing this? I need to do it on the fly and apply it to between 50-200 snippets like the one above (only a few of which include the title section).